# Why a file automatically created with '~' whenever I change the gedit file?

Tags: gedit

Whenever I made changes in my text files, automatically another file with the same name plus a '~' gets created. Why does this happen?

How can I prevent these files from getting auto-created?

These are two files I created and two which got automatically created:

[image]

Comment: i don't know what to do should I auto save or not he (@Bruno Pereira ) mentioned your system can crash